# Cloud sql proxy not working from docker container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-proxy

My application is running on docker container and deployed with google compute groups and autoscalling enabled. 
The problem iam facing is connecting mysql instance from auto-scaled compute instances but its not working expected.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
...installation other extenstion
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
    php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
COPY . /var/www/html
CMD cd /var/www/html
RUN composer install
ADD nginx.conf/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
RUN chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
RUN mkdir /cloudsql
RUN chmod 777 /cloudsql
RUN chmod 777 -R storage bootstrap/cache
EXPOSE 80
**CMD service php7.1-fpm start && nginx -g "daemon off;" &&  ./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=<connectionname>=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306 -credential_file=file.json &**
```

The last line `./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=<connectionname>=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306 -credential_file=file.json &` is not getting executed when I run my container.

If I run this `./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=<connectionname>=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306 -credential_file=file.json &` inside container (by going to container via docker command) it's working and when i close the terminal again its stop working.

Even I tried to run in background, but no luck.

Anyone have a idea of it?

Comment: did you try to change your latest command order and start with the sql proxy command?

Comment: Could you show the error logs of the Docker build? https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/

Comment: Now it's working

Comment: I put sleep 10 on shell script

Comment: Great!, It would be great if you added the files in the response and mark it as accepted! https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has been fixed by

1. Create start.sh file and move all command to start.sh
2. After start sql proxy I put sleep 10 and start the nginx and php

Now it's works as expected.

```
Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:16.04
...other command
ADD start.sh /
RUN chmod +x /start.sh
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

and this is start.sh file

```
//start.sh
#!/bin/sh
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=<connectionname>=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306     -credential_file=<file>.json &
sleep 10
service php7.1-fpm start
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```